# Calling method on temporary objects

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class in which I overloaded method. Depending on lifetime of the object given method will be called.

How can I call fun implementation for temporary objects? I thought that `std::move()` casts its argument to an rvalue. Could you tell me why the code below does not work as intended?

```cpp
template <typename T>
void fun(T&& arg) {
    arg.callamethod();
}
class TestCall {
private:

public:
    void callamethod() && {
        std::cout << "R VALUE REF" << std::endl;
    }

    void callamethod() const & {
        std::cout << "CONST L VALUE REF" << std::endl;

    }

     void callamethod() & {
        std::cout << "L VALUE REF" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
TestCall arg = TestCall();
const TestCall arg2 = TestCall();
fun(arg);
fun(arg2);
fun(std::move(arg)); // calls callamethod() &
fun(std::move(arg2)); // calls callamethod() const &
}
```

Comment: There are no temporary objects in your code. Indeed, `std::move()` is just a typecast, it does not create new objects. Inside of `fun()`, the `arg` parameter is a reference to an object, but the parameter itself has a name and thus is itself an lvalue, not an rvalue. It is effectively no different than doing `TestCall obj; TestCall &ref = obj; ref.callamethod();` That is why `arg.callamethod()` in `fun()` calls the lvalue overloads of `callamethod()`. You would have to do something like `TestCall().callamethod()` or `std::move(arg).callamethod()` to call the rvalue overload of `callamethod()`.

Comment: But I can also do it like this  ```std::forward<T>(arg).callamethod()```.?

Comment: @XYZ123 Yes, and it is better solution, because it works for both: Lvalue, and Rvalues passed to `fun`. `move` always casts to Rvalue, `forward` only if `fun` is called with Rvalue. The last line will print `const &` because `arg2` is const, and move operations (whose intention is to steal reasources) don't work with const instances.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function `fun` to the following code and you will see that rvalue qualifier on your method `callamethod` works as expected.

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T&& arg) {
    std::forward<T>(arg).callamethod();
}
```

Note that the last call:

```
fun(std::move(arg2));
```

resolves to the ***const lvalue*** option of `callamethod` as you do not have a ***const rvalue*** qualifier option, if you add one it will go to it.